# how to set category list limit?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am display post category child list.list display all  
i need display only 6 (child )
help with us...

ex:
menu (parent)
list1 (child)
list2 (child)
list3 (child)
list4 (child)
list5 (child)
list6 (child)
list7 (child)
list8 (child)

```
<?php $article_categories = get_categories(array(
                                    'child_of' => get_category_by_slug('work')->term_id
                            ));
    $talentChildren = get_categories(array('child_of' => get_category_by_slug('talent')->term_id));


 ?>
    <?php if ( have_posts()) : ?>
        <?php $talent_Children = array($talentChildren[0]); ?>
        <?php foreach($talent_Children as $talent): ?>
        <?php
        $talentSubChildren = new WP_Query();
        $talentSubChildren->query(array('category_name' => $talent->slug));
        ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>talent/directors/"><?php echo $talent->name; ?></a></h2>
        <ul>
        <?php while ($talentSubChildren->have_posts()) : $talentSubChildren->the_post(); ?>
        <li>
        <h4><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h4>
        </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can user number =6 in get_categories function like

```
$talentChildren = get_categories(array('child_of' => get_category_by_slug('news')->term_id,'number' => 6,'hide_empty' => 0));
foreach($talentChildren as $talent):
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($talent);
    echo "</pre>";
endforeach;
```

Comment: i receive -> syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW) how to solve this error

Comment: Have you try it?Working?

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 23
    [name] => Directors
    [slug] => directors
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 24
    [taxonomy] => category
    [description] =>
    [parent] => 15
    [count] => 6
    [cat_ID] => 23
    [category_count] => 6
    [category_description] =>
    [cat_name] => Directors
    [category_nicename] => directors
    [category_parent] => 15
)

Comment: its working fine and another help.now display [slug] => directors  [count] => display 6. i need display only 2.help with us

Comment: you can change number to 2

Comment: i have already change 2 but result is 1) stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 23
    [name] => Directors
    [slug] => directors
   )

2)stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 22
    [name] => Editors / Visual Artists
    [slug] => editors
)

Comment: stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 23
    [name] => Directors
    [slug] => directors
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 24
    [taxonomy] => category
    [description] =>
    [parent] => 15
    [count] => 6
    [cat_ID] => 23
    [category_count] => 6
    [category_description] =>
    [cat_name] => Directors
    [category_nicename] => directors
    [category_parent] => 15
)

directors child count is 6. i need display count 2

Comment: $talent_Children = array($talentChildren[0]); i have add 6 post. and display 6 post successfully. but i need display 2 post.help with us..